# Google Cloud MySQL External Connection Issue

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am attempting to connect an administration tool installed on a siteground site with Google Cloud MySQL.  When I try to connect, I get the following error message: Error: MySQL connect error #2003.  Cannot connect to MySQL server on {cloud instance ip address}

The tool works from my localhost.  The Cloud MySQL instance has an IPV4 address.  The IP address for my siteground site is entered in the allowed IP addresses (both the specific IP and the 0/24 range)

I am not seeing any errors in the MySQL log.

Any suggestions / assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: Can you use a site like ipv4.me to verify that the external address is what you think it is? Perhaps there is some NATing involved.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Siteground has a firewall blocking outbound connections on TCP port 3306, thus preventing the Cloud SQL connections.  They have some documentation about [requesting open ports](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_open_a_firewall_port_on_sitegrounds_server/) that might help.